# jQuery: call function without parentheses, but pass parrameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Is it possible to call jQuery function without parentheses, but at this time pass parameters to function?

I have situation like this:

**have declared jQuery function, which I want to run manually by call, not after DOM ready**

```
$(function() {

  function doosomething()
  {
    //Doo something
  }

  $("div").click(doosomething); //function is calling without "()"

});
```

if I put parentheses to function on call, it runs on DOM ready, not on click.
So What if I want to push some parameters to my doosimething function? like this:

```
doosomething(foo, bar)
```

Comment: Please check some examples at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) page.

Comment: pass an anonymous function to `.click()`, and have it invoke `dosomething`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 $("div").click(doosomething); //function is calling without "()"
```

do

```
 $("div").click(function() { doosomething(foo, bar); });
```

You want to pass a function that calls your function when invoked.

Comment: in this case, function doosomething runs on DOM ready, not on click

Comment: @zur4ik: No, it runs when the event occurs. Why do you think it runs on DOM ready?

Comment: Yes! it works! I was calling without `function() {}`, like this: `$("div").click(doosomething(foo, bar));` Thanks a lot.

Comment: This will work, and is useful if you're calling the `doSomething` function as part of a bigger set of instructions, but if your whole event handler is inside of `doSomething` then you're needlessly adding an extra anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

To pass variables to a jQuery event handler, do the following:

```
function doSomething(event) {
    var x = event.data.your_param_1;
    // do something
}

$('div').on('click', doSomething);

$('div').trigger('click', {your_param_1:some_variable});
```

See the jQuery API on the trigger() function for details: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-event-extraParameters

If you aren't manually triggering the click event:

```
$('div').on('click', {your_param_1:some_variable}, doSomething);
```

The `some_variable` var will still be evaluated at the time the click event is triggered by the user.

Comment: That'll work, though you're hard-coding the value. OP appears to be passing variables, and may want to have their values evaluated at the time of the event.

Comment: So then he'll pass a variable as `your_param_1` instead of a hardcoded value. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: Point is that the value of the variable will be evaluated when you assign it to the event data object.

Comment: And that occurs as it triggers the event whose handler (`doSomething` in this case) is expecting the value. Still not sure what your point is.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking you were binding event data on the assignment of the handler. Didn't look closely enough. So as long as the variable is within the scope of the triggering code, it'll work.

Comment: ...except that you're manually triggering the click event. It's not happening when the browser event occurs, which is what OP wants.

Comment: You can add the data to the event definition instead, and it'll still be evaluated at the time the event is triggered. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for details.

Comment: If you're talking about the event data object that can be passed to `.on()`, then no, it'll be evaluated when you assign the data to the object, and will not be re-evaluated when the event occurs.

Comment: I am talking about that, and you are incorrect. As stated by the documentation I linked to, as well as my experience using it in numerous places with the expected behavior.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have pointers. How do you expect it to evaluate the value of a variable that it doesn't keep a reference to? When you do an assignment in JavaScript, you get the value assigned, not a variable reference.

Comment: Yea, you're actually right. I guess I used the .trigger() method of sending data in the code I was referring to. Oh well.

Comment: Still a useful solution if OP doesn't need the variables evaluated when the event occurs. I can't tell exactly what he needs.

Comment: It's actually a better solution because you don't have to define the parameters in the method definition. It's easier to maintain imho.